# WPF MVVM Lost control properties

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a MVVM TimeLine (24h) UserControl, populate thanks to ItemsControl and UniformGrid, with a checkBox binded to a boolean property.

When I check the checkBox, the state of property changes well and my timeline is focused on 8 hours rolling, and I redraw the entire user control.

```
StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <ItemsControl x:Name="INMarks">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Rows="1"  Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=UCtrlTimeLineMainGrid}"  />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <Line X1="10" Y1="0" X2="10" Y2="10" Stretch="Fill" StrokeDashArray="1" Stroke="White"/>
                            <Label Content="{Binding SText}" Visibility="{Binding Visibility}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="9" Foreground="white"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
```

In the setter of this property I call a method which (re)draw the timeline. This method works fine in OnLoad event, but when I pass by the checkbox it doesn't work, as MVVM lost the controls. For more details, INMarks which is my ItemsControl is finded, but the element "Line" is null.

Do you know why ?

```
ContentPresenter c = (ContentPresenter)INMarks.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(INMarks.Items[INMarks.Items.Count - 1]);

        if (c != null)
        {
            Line line = FindVisualChild<Line>(c);
            if (line != null)
                this.iTimeLineWidth = (int)line.TransformToAncestor(this).Transform(new Point(0, 0)).X;
        }
```

Comment: This code doesn't even show the TimeLine xaml (is this stackpanel inside the timeline!?!?!).  Maybe make a better example that shows the complete code you are having a problem with.

Comment: XAML has been added on. For your information, when I check my checkbox and put a delay, it's working fine.

Here the code on the setter of the property binded to the CheckBox: 
this.INMarks.ItemsSource = this.xAxisIN.ListTickMarks;